# importing files residing in an unrelated path

Tags: python

Consider I have a directory called `root` that has two directories: `x` and `y`. I have a module file that resides in `x`, let us call that `test.py`. Now in `y`, I have a module that needs to call `test.py`

I am doing a simple:

`from x import test`

And it works. I was wondering, how this works?

EDIT: How it works, as in there was no `__init__.py` file in `x`, but yet from `y` I was able to call a module from there.

Comment: EDIT: I figured this out, since my original script was starting from `x` that is why this worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't. You, or your operating system, or your Python site startup scripts, have modified `PYTHONPATH`.

```
14:59 jsmith@upsidedown pwd
/Users/jsmith/Test/Test2/root

14:59 jsmith@upsidedown cat x/test.py
def hello():
  print "hello"

14:59 jsmith@upsidedown cat y/real.py
#!/usr/bin/python
from x import test
test.hello()

14:59 jsmith@upsidedown y/real.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "y/real.py", line 3, in <module>
    from x import test
ImportError: No module named x
```

Comment: I see. What would be the best way to import the module, akin to the case I mentioned above?

I will check my code later, but first I should know the method of doing it :)

Comment: `import sys`, then `sys.path.append("/full/path/to/root")`, and make sure there is an `__init__.py` in `root/x`.

Answer (score 0):

Because there's a path to it.  Try this:

```
import sys
print sys.path
```

That should output all the places python uses as the starting direcctory to resolve module locations.  So for example, if `root` is actually in /home/PulpFiction/root (or C:\Documents and Settings\PulpFiction\My Documents\root on windows), you'll see something like this:

```
['', '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages', *more stuff*, '/home/PulpFiction/root']
```

or on windows:

```
['', 'C:\\python26\\site-packages', *more stuff here*, 'C:\Documents and Settings\PulpFiction\My Documents\root']
```

There are a few ways `sys.path` can be set (that I know of):

1. The directory you run the script from
2. Environment variable (PYTHONPATH to be exact)
3. Windows Registry (on windows only obviously)
4. Manually appending a path to the sys.path variable yourself in the code

I'm guessing the reason it work for you is you have a script in `root` (let's say `main.py`), and that script end up importing from both `x` and `y`.  Since you're running the script in the root directory it's added to the python path, which allows `from x import test` to work.

EDIT

There's no `__init__.py` eh?  You sure there isn't an `__init__.pyc` there (note the C in pyc)?